# Java Spring creating response from template

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Until now when sending ajax requests, in our controller we did return JsonMessage and decorate the data in the client side. But recently we are using a third-party UI framework which accepts a ready to use HTML as ajax callback.

Is there a way to do this without bringing all the html markup to the controller? something like a post-processor which accepts JSON and a template, renders it and then sends it to the client?

Note: The response is in JSON format, which has an attribute containing that HTML.

We use springframework 4.2.6.

Comment: just handled it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422411/how-to-manually-render-spring-mvc-view-to-html

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to add some method into controller which returns [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) object.

Also you need to configure [ViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) and set view name and corresponding model in the [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) object.
Like this

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/html", produces = "application/json")
  public ModelAndView getUserHtml(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    return new ModelAndView("user", Collections.singletonMap("user", this.user));
  }
}
```

And you'll see response like this

```
{
  "response": "<div><h1>Java Spring creating response from template</h1><h2>User</h2><p>username: superuser</p><p>password: secret</p><p>email: superuser@mail.com</p></div></html>"
}
```

---

Working sample project: https://github.com/sandarkin/so-q37526576

Comment: I tried this, thanks, but this returns the html, not a json containing that html :\

Comment: OK. I have adjusted the sample project by forcibly setting the content type. And now http://localhost:8080/default/html will return json with the correct content type.