# StackOverFlowError when rendering view from Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have the following code (based in part from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422411/how-to-manually-render-spring-mvc-view-to-html) stackoverflow question:

```
        MockHttpServletResponse mockResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        mockResponse.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        mockResponse.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING);
        View resolvedView = viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName);
        resolvedView.render(modelMap, request, mockResponse);
        return mockResponse.getContentAsString();
```

Now for some cases, when the `mockResponse.getContentAsString()` gets called, a StackOverFlowError happens.

I can share the JSP but at a high level why would I get a stackoverflow error when trying to get the html content from the resolved view after its been rendered?

Comment: Why are you rendering the view manually? That's Spring's job.

Comment: @chrylist i am using the rendered view to replace HTML content via JS. Even if i dont want to do this, i have an inherited project in which im trying to solve this bug

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar situation:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13771

If it is this situation, you can change to the new springmvc version.